# ListView remains null

Tags: android, list, android-listview, android-activity, actionbarsherlock

I have a ListView in my `result_page.xml` under layouts.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/resultList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Below is a snippet of my activity

```
public class ResultActivity extends SherlockListActivity {
    ListView listView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result_page);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.resultList);
        ResultPageAdapter adapter = new ResultPageAdapter(this, resultBeanList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I try to debug, `listView` remains `null`. Am I missing out something?

Comment: Please post the code in ResultPageAdapter

Comment: @VikramV I mean  to say, it is null even at this point => listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.resultList);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `SherlockListActivity` and not a `SherlockActivity`. So, your layout must be:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And in your onCreate method:

```
public class ResultActivity extends SherlockListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result_page);

        ResultPageAdapter adapter = new ResultPageAdapter(this, resultBeanList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        //... 
    }

}
```

Set you adapter without find your id's `ListView`, then it should work!